# How to prevent NullPointerException in Java when referencing object in array which works fine when referenced directly

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

```
lblPt1.setIcon(bd.pt1.getImage());
```

works while

```
lblPt1.setIcon(bd.pts[0].getImage());
```

throws a NullPointerException

pts[] is an array containing "Point" objects pt1 through pt24.

I would like to handle it with this for loop where pointLbls[] is an array of JLabels:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        pointLbls[i].setIcon(bd.pts[i].getImage());
```

I have determined that it is the object that is null, not its associated image.
What am I doing wrong? I am rather new to programming.

Comment: How did you create that pts[]-array?
Give us a bit more code so we can see there the actual problem lies buried ;-)

Comment: I made the array using this:
`public Point[] pts = {pt1, ..., pt24};`

The constructor for the class in that array is in immediately instantiates the Points (it calls resetBoard):

`public void resetBoard() {
  pt1 = new Point(1, 2);
//etc for all points
}`

and the constructor for Point looks like this:

`public Point(int color, int num) {
   colorValue = color;
   numPieces = num;
   GameBoard.piecesOnBoard += num;
   addImage();
  }
 }`

I hope that's enough to work with, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: In the code you've just provided, if you really are initializing the array "public Point[] pts = {pt1, ..., pt24};" before you assign the points "pt1 = new Point(1, 2); //etc for all points }" then they will all be null.

Comment: if (bd == null) throw new NullPointerException("The variable 'bd' is already null!");
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   final JLabel label = pointLbls[i];
   if (label == null) throw new NullPointerException("The variable 'label' is already null!");
   
   final Point pt = bd.pts[i];
   if (pt == null) throw new NullPointerException("The variable 'pt' is already null!");
   
   final Icon icon = pt.getImage();
   if (icon == null) throw new NullPointerException("The variable 'icon' is already null!");
   
   // ... and finally...
   label.setIcon(icon);
  }

Comment: Thank you so much! [Backgammon](http://imgur.com/Qibnm3G) is back up and running thanks to you!

Why not submit a quick answer so I can give you the credit?

Comment: It has been marked as duplicate, and so no one can post any real answers anymore, just these short comments here...

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a Null check condition, try the code below:

```
for(int i=0; i<24; i++){
    Point temp = bd.pts[i]; // store point in a temporary variable
    if(temp != null) // check if it is null
        pointLbls[i].setIcon(temp.getImage()); // if not null, do what you want!
}
```

Comment: That's how I figured out the Point objects were null, but I can't tell why. They work fine when referenced without the array.